# Activate and Deactivate Invoke function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I attempted to give a delay to my function in Unity using C# language. By using `Invoke`, I achieved to add delay when the cursor is moved to a certain area. However, now I need to cancel the `Invoke` when the cursor is moved from that certain area. The idea is, when I accidentally move the cursor to the area, I can cancel whatever function being invoked there.
Here's my current code.

```
void SceneCall(){
    Application.LoadLevel (MainMenu);
}

void SceneCallIn(){
    Invoke ("SceneCall", 3f);
}
if (_newGameButton.Contains (Event.current.mousePosition)) {
        SceneCallIn();
    }
```

I tried to use `CancelInvoke()` as else, and it even doesn't want to invoke anymore when I move my cursor to `_newGameButton` afterwards. How do you cancel an Invoke then activate it once again? Thank you for your answer~

EDIT: Like @Programmer says in comments, what I exactly want to do is when my mouse is position at a certain point, timer will start counting. After 3 seconds 
`MainMenu` scene will be loaded. While the timer is counting and the pointer is moved away from that certain position, I want the timer to stop and I don't want the `MainMenu` scene to be loaded anymore.

Comment: Hmm, when you call "invoke" again, it will just invoke it again - no problem.

Comment: Have I done the right thing to put CancelInvoke() after else {} below the if (_newGameButton.Contains (Event.current.mousePosition))? because it immediately cancel the Invoke even before I move my cursor to _newGameButton?

Comment: @Mikuriin Let me get this straight. When your mouse is position at a certain point, timer will start counting. After 3 seconds `MainMenu` scene will be loaded. While the timer is counting and the pointer is moved away from that certain position, you want the timer to stop and you don't want the `MainMenu` scene  to be loaded anymore?

Comment: oh dang it, sorry, I can't even explain it properly. YES, that's what I mean @Programmer

Comment: OK. In which method have you placed the if-else block?

Comment: I place it in `OnGUI()` and on my previous question, @JoeBlow stated that it's so not recommended but when I try another way, it doesn't work even for loading the scene without `Invoke()`

Comment: @UmairM Just realized that you are using `OnGUI()`. You shouldn't be using that. You should be using the new Unity UI system. I was going to provide answer for both `OnGUI` and the new UI but you already have two answers.Try the answers you got.  If none of them worked for you then let me know.

Comment: @Programmer it doesn't well I'm still trying so may I try your provided answer? :(

Comment: @Programmer EDIT. I already accomplished it, thank you. Maybe you can still add your answer here anyway, In case other people have same problem with me, thank you.

Comment: also thank you very much to @JoeBlow I did it and turns out the answer from Ronaldo below is working for me.

Comment: @Mikuriin Nice.Happy coding!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you truly want to have "rollovers" and so on, here is a full tutorial:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36046495/294884

Really you will have to become totally expert in all that, before you can do it.

I must tell you again though:

For 15 years now, you should never use rollovers for any reason in interface.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem yesterday, but I solved simply calling again the invoke method.

Here is my code:

```
public void OnGazeEnter()
{
    InvokeRepeating("OnGazeStay", 0.0f, 1.0f / 30.0f);
}
public void OnGazeExit()
{
    CancelInvoke("OnGazeStay");
}
```

In your case, if you want to register more than one method, you will have to save some sort of `List<String> myMethods`, so you will be able to delete every method that you've registered.

Comment: this is quite right.  i would URGE you to add Debug.Log statements to both.

Comment: I agree because debugging is the clearest way to understand your algorithm's flow and internal states

Comment: Thank you @RonaldoFelipe ! It's working. I just realized you use three functions : `OnGazeEnter`, `OnGazeStay`, and `OnGazeExit`. Turns out I used only two and that's why it didn't worked.

Comment: Yes, the third is omited because your problem may be slightly different.